# Compile, run and insert highlighted inline code

Tags: jekyll

Is there any existing method of automatically compiling and running code highlights in jekyll pages, inserting the output into the target HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I've made such a thing. Code repository is here : https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllDoc

The result is here : http://jekyll.pygmeeweb.com/tests/

### How it works

A [rake task](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllDoc/blob/gh-pages/Rakefile) generates a new page from [a data file](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllDoc/blob/gh-pages/_data/tests.yml) which contains code snipped

Data are like

```
snippet: '{% assign my_array = "one|two" | split: "|" %}{{ my_array | push: "three" }}'
```

This snippet is inserted in [a template](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllDoc/blob/gh-pages/_test-template.html) used to create a [new page](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllDoc/blob/gh-pages/tests.html).

Then a Jekyll build will interpret the code in this new page.

Not so clear isn't it ?? Just ask I'll answer. New year lag...